# If $\{u,v,w\}$ is a linearly independent set of a vector space $V$, then what can you sat about the set $\{u+v, u-v, u-2v+w\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If $\{u,v,w\}$ is a linearly independent set of a vector space $V$, then prove or disprove that the set $\{u+v, u-v, u-2v+w\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $V$.

**My attempt:**

I couldn't really make any significant progress on this question. What I tried was to let scalars $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\alpha u+\beta v+\gamma w=0\implies \alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$$ and then tried proving the other set linearly dependent. $$\left(\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\right)(u+v)+\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\right)(u-v)+\gamma(u-2v+w)=0$$ $$\implies \alpha u+\beta v+\gamma(u-2v+w)=0$$ I have been stuck at this point for quite some time now.

Any hints or alternative approaches will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to follow the definition of linear independence. This means, if you have $\alpha(u+v)+\beta (u-v)+\gamma (u-2v+w)=0$, then you need to show that $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$, using the assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha(u+v)+\beta (u-v)+\gamma (u-2v+w)=0$

$\implies (\alpha+\beta+\gamma)u+(\alpha-\beta-2\gamma)v+ \gamma w=0$

$\{u,v,w\}$ linearly independent implies

$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=0\tag{1}$

$\alpha-\beta-2\gamma=0\tag{2}$

$\gamma=0\tag{3}$

Solving $(1), (2), (3) $ we get $$\alpha=?, \beta=?, \gamma=? $$